# Create different HTML ordered list

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get type of ordered list which is shown below any one please help to solve this.

How to get
(a)
(b)
(c)
This types of ol (with the brackets) in html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the [list marker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker) and using `list-item` [counter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Counter_Styles/Using_CSS_counters)

You can customize the `list-style-type` by changing the `lower-alpha` to [list style type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type)

```css
ol li::marker {
  content: "(" counter(list-item, lower-alpha) ") ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Change ``lower-alpha`` to ``upper-alpha`` for capital letters: ``(A)``, ``(B)``, ``(C)`` and so on.